# Template for front page (latest posts)

Tags: theme-development, templates, page-template

I am having

---

index.php -> This renders the latest post with sidebar

---

page.php-> This renders the page layout : Templates are fullwidth,sidebarleft& sidebarright

---

single.php-> This renders the single post layout : Templates are fullwidth,sidebarleft& sidebarright

---

whether a template can be provided for index.php? How can i provide option for full width, sidebarleft& sidebarright options for index.php?

Comment: In `Settings`->`Reading`, you can define any page as a template for both your front page and your posts page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether a template can be provided for index.php?

There's no built-in capability for selecting a custom template for archives.

> How can i provide option for full width, sidebarleft& sidebarright options for index.php?

You can add a generic [Customizer control](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/) with options for which template to use for archives, then inside index.php you would just check the saved value of that control with `get_theme_mod()` and change the template accordingly, or include another template file, for example:

```
switch ( get_theme_mod( 'layout' ) ) {
    case 'fullwidth':
        get_template_part( 'index', 'fullwidth' );
        break;
    case 'sidebarleft':
        get_template_part( 'index', 'sidebarleft' );
        break;
    case 'sidebarright':
        get_template_part( 'index', 'sidebarright' );
        break;
}
```